# Fixed-Do Solfege in A Major scale with accidentals

Tags: solfege

I am learning solfege by myself and I have a question about reading of notes with accidentals. As far as I studied, There are 2 different ways in solfege, fixed-do and movable-do. There are also variations such as chromatic and non-chromatic.
The image below is A major scale with accidentals.
[image: A major scale with with accidentals]

In movable-do/non-chromatic, it should be:

| do do re re | mi fa fa sol | sol la la ti | do do ti | ti la la sol | sol fa mi mi | re re do |

In movable-do/chromatic, it should be like:

| do di re ri | mi fa fi sol | si la li ti | do do ti | te la le sol | se fa mi me | re ra do |

But I am very confused with Fixed-do. I don't know how to read notes with accidentals. I am not sure but in fixed-do/chromatic should be like:

| la li ti do(?) | di re ri mi | fa(?) fi sol(?) si | la la si | sol fi fa mi | me re di do | ti te la |

Is that correct? Fixed-do/non-chromatic is more complicated. I have no idea whether I should just ignore accidentals or indicate actual note.
Ignoring accidentals is very easy but E sharp will be "mi", etc. and I feel it's very weird.

| la la ti ti | do re re mi | mi fa fa sol | la la sol | sol fa fa mi | mi re do do | ti ti la |

Is that correct? Does anyone know the standard way of fixed-do solfege in the scale with key signature and accidentals?
Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Hugely related, if not actually a duplicate: https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/33858/are-there-solfege-syllables-for-diminished-and-augmented-imperfect-intervals

Comment: @AndrewLeach it is closely related, but might be hard to find "fixed vs. movable" in that answer via simple searches.

Comment: I wouldn't call that scale an "A major", but I could be wrong. The way you said it omits that it is chromatic and not just the 7-tone scale with mostly whole steps.

Comment: @LeifWillerts - I read it as such initially. OP means 'A major scale - with accidentals. Accidentals are those # and b NOT included in the key sig.

Comment: This question is so distorted - unclear what is being asked, AND it somehow seems like if Sekine is asking multiple questions at once.  Downvoted and voted to close. -1.

Answer (score 5):

the names are like Tim says correctly "do-dièse" (C#) and "mi bémol" (Eb) etc.
These expressions  are used to name  the key! 
Examples: 
Bach: Messe an Si- mineur

or:

https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suites_fran%C3%A7aises

Bach:

1.1 Suite française no 1 en ré mineur, BWV 812
1.2 Suite française no 2 en ut mineur, BWV 813
1.3 Suite française no 3 en si mineur, BWV 814
1.4 Suite française no 4 en mi bémol majeur, BWV 815
1.5 Suite française no 5 en sol majeur, BWV 816
1.6 Suite française no 6 en mi majeur, BWV 817

Rachmaninov, Prelude en do dièse mineur (-> C# minor)

But actually the French just sing the non-altered name - also DO for C# and MI for Eb etc. and the rest (sharps and flats they think or mind as it is written in the sheet notes:

the list you are asking for is here:

[image]
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solf%C3%A8ge

***"In the fixed do system, shown above, accidentals do not affect the syllables used. For example, C, C♯, and C♭ (as well as Cdouble sharp and Cdouble flat, not shown above) are all sung with the syllable "do".***

Answer (score 4):

Fixed do, as used in France, therefore I'll use the French version, would use *diese* for sharp, and *bemol* for flat. So F♯ is called *fa-diese*, and B♭ is called *si-bemol*. I don't thnk it's productive to call, as in your first example, both A and A♯ (in movable, key A) as *do*, because it somewhat defeats the objective.

Comment: I agree with you, Tim, but the French do so. (And I wonder how they can mind and recognize the key without notes. (While the English spelling of the absolute names like Bflat, Eflat is correct but not very comfortable and "musically" for singing.)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for responding to my question.
I think I understood about fixed-do solfege thanks to your comments and the information from websites [Jody Nagel's page](https://www.jomarpress.com/nagel/articles/Solfeg.html) and [reddit issue](https://www.reddit.com/r/musictheory/comments/8qjpwa/fixeddo_solf%C3%A8ge_of_b_and_e/).

From my understanding, traditionally, fixed-do solfege is non-chromatic.
So, Fixed-Do / Non-chromatic syllables for the music above is:
[image: A major scale in fixed-do/non-chromatic]

It seems weird for me because E# is sung as "mi", etc., but it's the rule here.

There are also newly devised system to differentiate chromatic notes.
By using Shearer's system, fixed-do/chromatic syllables for the music above is:
[image]

Now, everything is clear. Thank you!